# Is this a clang bug or something I don't know about C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

While looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446385/trouble-with-cast-operators-converting-to-visual-studio-2013) question I tried it out with clang and got in a weird situation. The following example:

```
#include <string>

class ACP
{
public:
    ACP() {}
    operator const std::string() const  { return std::string(); }
    // operator std::string() const  { return std::string(); } <-- makes clang happy
};

void test()
{
   const ACP acp;
   auto a = (std::string)acp;
}
```

compiles fine on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3396df88e3a4a118) with gcc, but fails with clang. At least I see no issue with this example - is this a bug in clang or is there a rule that actually explains the clang error and gcc is wrong?

The error from clang can be seen below:

```
clang -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:13:26: error: no viable conversion from 'const ACP' to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'
   auto a = (std::string)acp;
                         ^~~
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.0/../../../../include/c++/7.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:421:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const ACP' to 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> &' for 1st argument
      basic_string(const basic_string& __str)
      ^
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.0/../../../../include/c++/7.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:493:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const ACP' to 'const char *' for 1st argument
      basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
      ^
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.0/../../../../include/c++/7.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:515:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const ACP' to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> &&' for 1st argument
      basic_string(basic_string&& __str) noexcept
      ^
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.0/../../../../include/c++/7.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:542:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const ACP' to 'initializer_list<char>' for 1st argument
      basic_string(initializer_list<_CharT> __l, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
      ^
main.cpp:7:5: note: candidate function
    operator const std::string() const  { return std::string(); }
    ^
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.0/../../../../include/c++/7.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:515:35: note: passing argument to parameter '__str' here
      basic_string(basic_string&& __str) noexcept
                                  ^
1 error generated.
```

However I can't see why the compiler could not use the copy ctor from `std::string`.

Comment: clang looks a bit suspect to me, but returning a const object is likely to be a logic error or misunderstanding on your part. Are you sure you don't want to return a reference to const string?

Comment: `std::string a = acp;` instead of `auto a = (std::string)acp;` works in clang if that helps in any way.

Comment: Actually, just adding `explicit` in front of the operator also makes Clang happy... `explicit operator const std::string() const  { return std::string(); }`

Comment: Isn't this asking for two implicit user-defined conversions, when only one is allowed? First conversion `ACP->const std::string`, second conversion `const std::string->std::string` (via copy constructor)

Comment: @RichardHodges Returning a `const` object instead of a non-const is (was) actually a recommended practice by Scott Meyer, at least it was for C++03 (if I remember correctly).

Comment: @MicroVirus I think Scott Meyer's exhortation to "use const whenever possible" is sometimes taken to counterproductive extremes. A const object is by definition, not moveable. So when one is returned by value it begs the compiler to copy the returned object and then dump it (until c++17 when RVO is mandatory). The objects it's copied into may or may not be const, at the caller's whim, so the entire rationale of returning a const object is broken from the start.

Comment: @RichardHodges as I said, I took the example from another SO question. I would not have used `const`, but I could not find an explanation why using `const` would result in an error.

Comment: @Useless Is `const std::string->std::string` really categorized as a user-defined conversion?

Comment: @cppleaner I also initially though about two user-defined conversions, but that should not be the case.

Comment: it's a non-explicit single-argument constructor, so ... maybe?

Comment: @RichardHodges That's why it was a C++03 recommendation.

Comment: @MicroVirus I don't follow. My position is that even in c++03, returning a const object is a pointless thing to do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simplified:

```
struct A {};
struct B { operator const A(); };
B b;
A a(b);
```

This is [direct-initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#def:direct-initialization) with [destination type class type](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2) `A`, so [candidate constructors](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ctor) of `A` are enumerated, selecting all the constructors of A (including the implicitly defined copy and move constructors) and compared by [overload resolution](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match) for [direct-initialization of a class object](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#2.4). First the constructors are assessed for [viability](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#viable), which means attempting to construct an [implicit conversion sequence](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#def:implicit_conversion_sequence) from `b` (an lvalue `B`) to their parameter. Since the parameter is a reference (`A const&` or `A&&`) we must perform a [reference initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref). We can [initialize a reference](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.2.1.2) `A const&` from `b` since `b` can be converted to an rvalue `A const`, and `A const` (the type of the target reference) and `A const` (the return type of the target function) are [reference-compatible](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#def:reference-compatible) (since they are the same cv-qualified type); indeed, this is a [direct reference binding](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref). We cannot initialize a reference `A&&` from `b` since `A&&` [has lesser cv-qualification](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.2.2.3) than `A const`. So `A::A(A const&)` is the only viable constructor and is selected.

This has been reported to clang multiple times [1](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26457) [2](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27914) [3](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27949) but unfortunately hasn't been picked up.

All other major compilers (gcc, ICC, MSVC) compile the code correctly.

Interestingly, as discussed [here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27949) clang compiles the code correctly in C++03 mode. If we force `A` to be a "C++03-style" type by suppressing its move constructor, clang will compile the resulting code:

```
struct A { A(A const&) = default; };
struct B { operator const A(); };
B b;
A a(b);
```

This indicates that perhaps clang is getting confused by the move constructor. It shouldn't, since the move constructor is not viable; `A&& a = b;` is invalid.